How to config EF Core with three objects?
Why does RoleIds work, but VoteId does not?
I am getting this error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The property 'Id' cannot be added to the type 'User.VoteId#VoteId' because no property type was specified and there is no corresponding CLR property or field. To add a shadow state property, the property type must be specified.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance.

public sealed class User : AggregateRoot<UserId, Guid>
{
    // public UserId Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; private set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<RoleId> RoleIds => _RoleIds.AsReadOnly();
    private readonly List<RoleId> _RoleIds = new();

    public VoteId? VoteId => _VoteId;
    private VoteId? _VoteId ;

    public User(UserId UserId, VoteId VoteId,
                string email,
                string firstName,string lastName, string password)
                    : base(UserId)
    {
        Email = email;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        PasswordHash = password;
    }

    public static User Create(string email,
                                string firstName, string lastName, string password)
    {
        var Users = new User(
            UserId.CreateUnique(), VoteId.CreateUnique(),
            email,
            firstName, lastName, password);

        //Users.AddDomainEvent(new UsersCreated(Users));

        return Users;
    }

    public void AddNewTicket(RoleId TicketId)
    {
        _RoleIds.Add(TicketId);
    }

    #pragma warning disable CS8618
    private User() { }
    #pragma warning restore CS8618
}

Config:
internal sealed class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Users");
        builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);

        builder
            .Property(m => m.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(
                id => id.Value,
                value => UserId.Create(value));

        builder.HasIndex(u => u.Email).IsUnique();
        ConfigureTicketIdsTable(builder);
        ConfigureUserIdsTable(builder);
    }

    private void ConfigureUserIdsTable(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsOne(m => m.VoteId, reviewBuilder =>
        {
            reviewBuilder.ToTable("VoteIdsUser");

            reviewBuilder
                .WithOwner()
                .HasForeignKey("UserId");

            reviewBuilder.HasKey("Id");

            reviewBuilder
                .Property(r => r.Value)
                .HasColumnName("VoteId")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();
        });

        builder.Metadata
            .FindNavigation(nameof(User.VoteId))!
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }

    private void ConfigureTicketIdsTable(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsMany(m => m.RoleIds, reviewBuilder =>
        {
            reviewBuilder.ToTable("RoleIds");

            reviewBuilder
                .WithOwner()
                .HasForeignKey("UserId");

            reviewBuilder.HasKey("Id");

            reviewBuilder
                .Property(r => r.Value)
                .HasColumnName("RoleId")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();
        });

        builder.Metadata
            .FindNavigation(nameof(User.RoleIds))!
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}


Please include the missing code of other involved classes, including the Id classes.
